# RxJs Array of Observable to Observable of Array

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, observable

For a Web-Application written with Angular2 in TypeScript, I need to work with RxJs `Observable`s.
As I never used rxjs before and I am new to reactiveprogramming in general, I sometimes have some difficulties finding the right way to do some specific things.
I am now facing a problem. where I have to convert an `Array<Observable<T>>` into an `Observable<Array<T>>`.
I'll try to explain it with an example:

- I have an `Observable`, which gives me a list of `Users` (`Observable<Array<User>>`)
- The `User`-class has a function `getPosts` returning an `Observable<Array<Post>>`.
- I need to map the `Observable<Array<User>>` to an `Observable<Array<Post>>` to evaluate all the `Post`s inside the `onNext` function.

I can easily map from `Observable<Array<User>>` to `Observable<Array<Observable<Array<Post>>>>` using
`map((result : Array<User>) => result.map((user : User) => user.getPosts()))`
and I can flatten an `Array<Array<Post>>` into an `Array<Post>`.
However I just can't find the correct way to map the `Observable<Array<Observable<Array<Post>>>>` into an `Observable<Array<Array<Post>>>`
Until now i used the `combineLatest` function together with `flatMap`.
To me it seemed to work and the editor i used (Atom editor) did not show any error. However now I use Netbeans, which shows me an error in this code. Also compiling the code using "tsc" results in the following errors:

```
Argument of type '(result: Post[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NextObserver<[Observable<Post>]> | ErrorObserver<[Observable<Post>]> | CompletionObserver<[...'.
Type '(result: Post[]) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: [Observable<Post>]) => void'.
```

So my question is:
How can I "flatten" an `Array` of `Observables` into an `Array`?

Comment: What does the `getPosts` method correspond to? Does it load the posts of a specific user?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `flatMap` operator allows to do that. I don't fully understand what you try to do but I'll try to provide an answer...

If you want load all the

```
getPostsPerUser() {
  return this.http.get('/users')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .flatMap((result : Array<User>) => {
      return Observable.forkJoin(
        result.map((user : User) => user.getPosts());
    });
}
```

`Observable.forkJoin` allows you to wait for all observables to have received data.

The code above assumes that `user.getPosts()` returns an observable...

With this, you will receive an array of array of posts:

```
this.getPostsPerUser().subscribe(result => {
  var postsUser1 = result[0];
  var postsUser2 = result[1];
  (...)
});
```

Comment: Yea the `getPosts()` returns an `Observable<Array<Post>>`. So I guess thats what I am looking for. I'll try it out asap and let you know if it worked. Thanks

Comment: Works perfectly. I only hat to replace `combineLatest` with `forkJoin`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

You can use the function apply on the rxjs method you want, like this:

```js
const source1 = Rx.Observable.interval(100)
  .map(function (i) { return 'First: ' + i; });

const source2 = Rx.Observable.interval(150)
  .map(function (i) { return 'Second: ' + i; });

const observablesArray = [source1, source2];

const sources = Rx.Observable.combineLatest
.apply(this, observablesArray).take(4)

/* or you can write it without "apply" this way:
const sources = Rx.Observable
                .combineLatest(...observablesArray)
                .take(4)
*/
sources.subscribe(
  (response) => {
    console.log(response);
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.1/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I guess this should work to, but I'll stick with `forkJoin` for now.

Answer (score 5):

Here is some example code using rxjs@6.3.3

```
import { of, forkJoin} from 'rxjs';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

const source:Array<Observable<String>> = [of('A'), of('B'), of('C') ];

forkJoin(source).subscribe( (x)=> console.log(x))
```

https://arrayofobservablesexamp.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 4):

Use forkJoin on this array of observables, then it will be an observable of array.

Answer (score 0):

Using `toArray()`

```
range(0, 7).pipe(
  concatMap(v => of(`day_${v}`)),
  toArray() // here
).subscribe(a => {
  console.log(a); // ['day_0', 'day_1', ... 'day_6']
});
```