# Javascript Observable - get snapshot in time

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I understand that an `Observable` is a dynamic object, that changes over time.  I am however, looking to create a function, that will return just a single snapshot of that observable.

I have the following function, that uses `AngularFire2` and returns an `Observable`.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

    findMessages(chatItem: any): Observable<any[]> {
        return this.af.database.list('/message/', {
            query: {
                orderByChild: 'negativtimestamp'
            }
        }).map(items => {
            const filtered = items.filter(
                item => ((item.memberId1 === chatItem.memberId1 && item.memberId2 === chatItem.memberId2)
                    || (item.memberId1 === chatItem.memberId2 && item.memberId2 === chatItem.memberId1))
            );
            return filtered;
        });
    }
```

This works perfectly, and if I display this list, it dynamically updates as items are added or removed.

**Question**

How do I call this function, and convert the `Observable` to a static array of items?

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984059/rxjs-array-of-observable-to-array) and tried to retrofit their example to my situation, but cannot seem to do so.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe to your `Observable` when you call your function. Actually you can't return anything from `Promise` or `Observable` because they are asynchronous. So you need to get the chain and use your variable there.

```
findMessages(char).subscribe((data) => {
 // it is the success function. Data is the one returned from the map
 // yourVariable = data;
});
```