# RxJS and angular.io: an Observable<Array<T>> where T contains an observable array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Indeed, I *did* try to find a similar question to this one as I find it hard to accept that it has not been asked before (even though it might be of an anti-pattern). Let us start with this component:

```
@Component({...})
export class MyParent {
    myGroups: Observable<Array<MyItemGroup>>;
}
```

where `MyItemGroup` is:

```
export class MyItemGroup {
    groupDisplayName: string;
    group: Observable<Array<MyGroupedItem>>;
}
```

First of all, is this arrangement some kind anti-pattern? Is there another grouping design that is regarded as correct in angular.io? To avoid the classic answer, "it depends," let us go further and see that:

```
export class MyGroupedItem {
    title: string;
    uri: string;
}
```

At the `MyParent` level, I would like to filter `MyGroupedItem` by `title` and, when this filter reduces the count of `MyItemGroup.group` to zero, I would like to filter out `MyItemGroup` entirely. This strongly suggests to me that I must add `mySubject` to `MyParent`:

```
@Component({...})
export class MyParent {
    myGroups: Observable<Array<MyItemGroup>>;
    mySubject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

    filterMyGroups(particle: string): void {
        this.mySubject.next(particle);
    }
}
```

It is here that I assume I need to go to town with RxJS, combining `myGroups` and `mySubject`. How does one do that? The UI would refer to `mySubject` through this markup:

```
<input #myFilter (keyup)="filterMyGroups(myFilter.value)" />
```

I can only hope the hope of the captive that my questions are understood and clear.

Comment: What is the purpose of `mySubject`, why do you really need `MyItemGroup.group` to be an Observable?

Comment: To avoid 'it depends', the question should contain real-world example that explains why you ended up with this sort of design. It will be clear then if it can be improved then. angular.io is website name. Framework's name is Angular.

Comment: I'll try change the concept and use forkJoin to subscribe a large serie of Observables

Comment: @Eliseo, yes, this answer is close: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984059/rxjs-array-of-observable-to-array/36984559?stw=2#36984559

Comment: @estus here is my working (but flawed), real-world example: https://github.com/BryanWilhite/angular.io-index-app/blob/master/index-app/src/app/components/app-index-groups/app-index-groups.component.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to set the items as an observables.

Here's something you can do:

- You `combineLatest` of the data API observable and the search filter input changes. Then you run observable `map` on it.
  The `map` will take a string (the filter), and an array of groups.
- Inside that observable `map`, you need basic array mapping and filtering.
  You get an array of groups as I mentioned, so, you can:

  - call the **array** `map` function to return new array of groups, each group is the same, except its `items` array is filtered using the filter string
  - then take the result of that and call **array** `filter` on it so you return only the groups where `items.length > 0`
- Then your group component just deals with a simple group object, passed to it, nothing related to observables there. Optionally you can split the item into its own component but you don't have to

Here's some code for the 2nd step:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
  <p>
    Start editing to see some magic happen :)
  </p>

  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <label>
      Search
      <input type="search" formControlName="search" />
    </label>
  </form>

  <h2>Items</h2>
  <app-group 
    *ngFor="let group of groups$ | async"
    [group]="group" ></app-group>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(
    private service: GroupsService
  ) { }

  groupData$ = this.service.getGroups();

  form = new FormGroup({
    search: new FormControl('')
  });

  searchFilter$ = this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
    // the map gets an arg in shape of `{search: 'value of search input'}`
    map((newFormValue: { search: string }) => newFormValue.search)
  );

  // `combineLatest` returns values from observables passed to it * as array *
  groups$ = combineLatest(
    this.groupData$,
    // We need to show data without waiting for filter change
    this.searchFilter$.pipe(startWith(''))
  ).pipe(
    map(([groups, searchFilter]) =>
      groups
        .map(group => this.filterItemsInGroup(group, searchFilter))
        .filter(group => group.items.length > 0)
    )
    );

  private filterItemsInGroup(group: ItemGroup, searchFilter: string) {
    if (!searchFilter) {
      return group;
    }

    return {
      // Copy all properties of group
      ...group,
      // This is NOT observable filter, this is basic array filtering
      items: group.items.filter(item =>
        item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFilter.toLowerCase())
        >= 0
      )
    };
  }
}
```

Here's a full working sample with all pieces:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-geujrq?embed=1&file=app/app.module.ts&hideExplorer=1&hideNavigation=1

The sample adds a few optimizations (like separating item into its own component and using `OnPush` change tracking for slightly faster output. More optizations could be added, like using `trackBy` for example.

### Update

The original poster came on Twitter and [explained his situation was more complex](https://twitter.com/BryanWilhite/status/945068106417815552).

He wanted

- the groups to be created dynamically from the items list
- a drop down to choose which field to group the items based on
- the items in each group to be hidden by default, and visible when you click the group name

This actually makes the problem of hiding groups easier, because you can filter the items BEFORE you group them.

Also the hiding of items does not have to be part of this problem at all. If your group is in its own component, you can have a boolean in that component that hides the items by default, and you flip it on group name click.

Let's see the code for this bit first because it's the easiest:
(styles and other bits are omitted, but I'll link to updated full sample below)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-group',
  template: `
      <h3 
        class="group-name"
        (click)="showItems = ! showItems"
        >{{group.displayName}}</h3>
      <ng-container *ngIf="showItems">
        <app-item 
          *ngFor="let item of group.items" 
          [item]="item"
          ></app-item>
      </ng-container>
  `
})
export class GroupComponent {
  @Input() group: ItemGroup;

  showItems = false;
}
```

Now let's go back to the listing problem. What we need to do is:

- Add a new grouping kind dropdown to the form that had the filter
- Use `switchMap` or whatever to connect the form to the service, and get one observable with items, search filter, and grouping kind
- Map each array we get from the result of calling array or form change to a new array that is filtered by search filter input value
- Map the filtered array of items to an array of groups using the value from grouping kind dropdown and, and hand that off to UI template

  - The specific logic of grouping can be complex if done by hand (like I did in the sample), but can be much reduced using something like Lodash

Let's look at the whole code:

Note how simple the setting of the `groups$` property it. The only complexity was in applying grouping really.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
  <p>
    Start editing to see some magic happen :)
  </p>

  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <label>
      Group
      <select formControlName="groupingKind">
        <option 
          *ngFor="let grouping of GroupingKinds"
          value="{{grouping}}">{{grouping}}</option>
      </select>
    </label>
    <label>
      Filter
      <input type="search" formControlName="search" />
    </label>
  </form>

  <h2>Items</h2>
  <app-group 
    *ngFor="let group of groups$ | async"
    [group]="group" ></app-group>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(
    private service: GroupsService
  ) { }

  // To make the template see it
  readonly GroupingKinds = Object.keys(GroupingKind)
    .map(key => GroupingKind[key]);

  form = new FormGroup({
    search: new FormControl(''),
    // Defaults to ByDate
    groupingKind: new FormControl(GroupingKind.ByDate)
  });

  // This will make a new HTTP request with every form change
  // If you don't want that, just switch the order
  //     of `this.form.valueChanges` and `this.service.getItems()`
  groups$ = this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
    // initial load
    startWith(this.form.value as {search: string, groupingKind: GroupingKind}),
    switchMap((form) =>
       this.service.getItems().pipe(
         // Take every array the `getItems()` returns
         //   (which is why we use observable `map` not observable `filter`)
         // And then transform it into another array
         //   that happenes to be the same array but filtered
         map(items => this.filterItems(items, form.search)),
         // Then map the result into group
         map(items => this.createGroups(items, form.groupingKind))
      )
    ),
  );

  private filterItems(items: ItemGroupItem[], searchFilter: string) {
    return items.filter(item =>
        item.Title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFilter.toLowerCase())
        >= 0
      );
  }

  private createGroups(src: ItemGroupItem[], groupingKind: GroupingKind) {
    const groupsList = [] as ItemGroup[];

    src.reduce((groupsObject, item) => {
      // Topic groups values are an array, date grouping value is a string, 
      // So we convert date grouping value to array also for simplicity
      const groupNames = groupingKind == GroupingKind.ByTopic
        ? item.ItemCategory.topics
        : [ item.ItemCategory.dateGroup ];

      for(const groupName of groupNames) {

        if(!groupsObject[groupName]) {
          const newGroup: ItemGroup = {
            displayName: groupName,
            items: []
          };
          groupsObject[groupName] = newGroup;      
          groupsList.push(newGroup);    
        }

        groupsObject[groupName].items.push(item);
      }

      return groupsObject;
    }, {} as { [name:string]: ItemGroup} );

    return groupsList;
  }
}
```

And as promised, here's the full updated sample:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-19z4f1?embed=1&file=app/app.module.ts&hideExplorer=1&hideNavigation=1

Comment: So the answer to my fist question is clearly yes: attaching observables to plain-old JS objects is an anti-pattern in angular as Meligy clearly shows that `FormGroup` and `FormControl` turns an HTML form into a reactive subject, piping into an observable based on plain-old JS objects.

Comment: It's not the form specifically. It's just that usually if you feel that you want a child property observable, quite often what you need is the parent observable, mixed with another observable maybe (via mergeMap/switchMap/Zip etc) -- which in this case was the form, and then transforming the entire object (via map and applying changes to the child properties inside it).

Comment: So in fewer words: instead of having observables for the child properties, just map values from the parent observable, and you might need to mix it with other observables to get enough params for the map