# How to return an observable from an array of observables

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

I started to play around with Angular 6 and Firebase. I wanted to use Hacker News API for displaying feeds (things).

I wanted to return an observable of an array of Thing class. Firstly I need an array of feed IDs, so I make a call to Firebase to fetch these. Then I wanted to fetch the feeds for each ID I already have, and return it as a single observable of an array of feeds.

What I have so far is the code like this:

```
getThings(limit: number): Observable<any> {
  return this.db.list('/v0/beststories', ref => ref.limitToFirst(limit).orderByKey())
    .valueChanges() // returns an Observable of IDs
    .pipe(
      flatMap(itemIds => {
        if (itemIds.length > 0) {
          let sources = itemIds.map(itemId => defer(() => {
            let pathOrRef = '/v0/item/' + itemId;
            return this.db.object(pathOrRef).valueChanges();
          }));
          // sources are the array of Observables
          return forkJoin(sources);
        } else {
          return Observable.create([]);
        }
      })
    );
}
```

I thought that flatMapping from the array would be the solution, but I get `You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable`.

I tried to do this in similar way as it's in [RxJs Array of Observable to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984059/rxjs-array-of-observable-to-array?noredirect=1&lq=1) , but I don't know where I made a mistake.

The error is thrown after invoking subscribe on the returned Observable:

```
this.hackerNewsService.getThings(20).subscribe(console.log);
```

The similar situation I reproduce in the following snippet: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8qtokd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I think `flatMap` takes an observable as return like you did in `else`. So you need to either use `of` or make another http call inside `flatMap` and return the observable.

Comment: Where's the error thrown? Is it even in this `flatMap`?

Comment: @windmaomao I don't know exatly what you mean by 'another call inside flatMap'. Could you show it in some snippet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `switchMap` and `combineLatest`. e.g.

```
import {combineLatest, Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map, switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

function getThings(limit: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.db.list('/v0/beststories', ref => ref.limitToFirst(limit).orderByKey())
        .valueChanges() // returns an Observable of IDs
        .pipe(
            switchMap(itemIds => {
                if (itemIds.length > 0) {
                    let sources = itemIds.map(itemId => {
                        let pathOrRef = '/v0/item/' + itemId;
                        return this.db.object(pathOrRef).valueChanges();
                    });
                    // sources are the array of Observables
                    return combineLatest(sources);
                } else {
                    return Observable.create([]);
                }
            })
        );
}
```