# Why is it not possible to return a forkJoin?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I don't understand why I can do

```
ForkJoin(service.Obs1(), service.Obs2()).subscribe
```

But if I refactor my code such that I add a method to my service class that returns `ForkJoin(this.Obs1(), this.Obs2())`, such as for example

```
updateWhatever(): Observable<[string, string]> {
return forkJoin([
  this.Obs1(),
  this.Obs(2)
]);}
```

Then if I do `service.updateWhatever().subscribe(res => //handle res[].`, it throws the error

> `You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable`

Why won't this work? One should be able to refactor in such a fashion. What am I missing? I realize it's returning an array of observables, but why should the function call not handle this?

Maybe my question is, how does one handle a method that returns a forkJoin ?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51231667/how-to-return-an-observable-from-an-array-of-observables

Comment: why are you passing an array to the second forkJoin?

Comment: @Axel  it's possible to return forkJoin , In your code the problem is ob1 and ob2 are not an observable,promise,array or Iterable.That's why rxjs throwing an error. can you share ob1 and obj2 code also

Comment: @Axel, which version of Rxjs are you using?

Comment: @Axel I have added a code sample for you. May be that also will get some idea

Comment: @NinaJami, all the arg are observables, they all do for example `return public getItem(): Observable<Item>`

Answer (score 2):

Specific to Rxjs 5 or earlier:

**[`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)** doesn't expect an `Array` of Observable(s). It expects source(s) of type **[`SubscribableOrPromise`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~SubscribableOrPromiseDoc.html)**

You'll have to do it like this:

```
updateWhatever() {
  return forkJoin(
    this.Obs1(),
    this.Obs(2)
  );
}
```

Comment: This is not true, at least with RxJS 6, see https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin

Comment: The point is that forkJoin is defined with a rest parameter, and not just one normal array type argument. The `...` before `sources` indicates this.

Comment: I Agree with @Picci , we can pass array of observable in forkJoin also

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to return a forkJoin.In your code the problem is **Obs1** and **Obs2** are not an observable,promise,array or Iterable.That's why rxjs throwing an error.

I Agree @Picci comment, we can pass array of observable in **forkJoin** also

**Sample Code**

```
const a = stream('a', 200, 3, 'partial');
const b = stream('b', 500, 3, 'partial');

someMethod().subscribe((response)=>{
  console.log(response);
});

someMethodFkAsAnArray().subscribe((response)=>{
  console.log(response);
});


function someMethod(){
  return forkJoin(a, b);
}

function someMethodFkAsAnArray(){
  return forkJoin([a, b]);

}
```

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fork-join-returns?file=main.ts) using RxJs 5.5.2

Comment: They are observables. For example `public getItem(): Observable<Item>`

Comment: @Axel which version of RxJs you are using?