# Trouble retrieving data from inner observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, ionic4

I'm having a problem with this code. I'm trying to collect extra details from a secondary endpoint that relates to the id in the returned collection from the first get.  Can someone help on *how to get the actual data out as its returning an array of observables*.  Thank you

```
this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/cinemas/location/cardiff`).pipe(
  map((data: any) => data.cinemas),
  map((cinemalist) => {
    return cinemalist.map(value => <Observable<any>>this.http.get(`https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/cinema/${value.id}`));
  })
).subscribe(results => {
  console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984059/rxjs-array-of-observable-to-array) out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.http.get(`https://api.cinelist.co.uk/search/cinemas/location/${town}`).pipe(
      map((data: any) => data.cinemas),
      flatMap((cinemas) =>
        forkJoin(
          cinemas.map(value => {
            return this.http.get(`https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/cinema/${value.id}`).pipe(
              map((result: any) => {
                return { ...result, ...value };
              }));
          })
        )
      )
    ).subscribe(x => {
      console.log(x);
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of a `map`, you can do a `switchMap` with a `forkJoin`:

```
this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/cinemas/location/cardiff`).pipe(
  map((data: any) => data.cinemas),
  switchMap((cinemas) => forkJoin(cinemas.map(value => <Observable<any>>this.http.get(`https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/cinema/${value.id}`));
  }))
).subscribe(results => {
  console.log(results);
});
```

If you want to keep the value, you can try something like that:

```
this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/cinemas/location/cardiff`).pipe(
  map((data: any) => data.cinemas),
  switchMap((cinemas) => forkJoin(cinemas.map(value => <Observable<any>>this.http.get(`https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/cinema/${value.id}`))
    .pipe(map(cinema => {...cinema,value}))
  }))
).subscribe(results => {
  console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: So it turns out i need to keep the original value held for each cinema ( value ).  How would i create a result that combined both the original value in addition to the results of the get in the subquery?

Comment: this.http.get(`https://api.cinelist.co.uk/search/cinemas/location/${town}`).pipe(
      map((data: any) => data.cinemas),
      switchMap((cinemas) =>
        forkJoin(
          cinemas.map(value => <Observable<any>>this.http.get(`https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/cinema/${value.id}`))
        )
      )
    ).subscribe(x => {
      console.log(x);
    });

Comment: adding the pipe freaks it out completely?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't test it, sorry.