# Angular nested Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a fuction inside my service which returns an observable array of entity ids and I have another function, which takes an entity id, with which I can get detailed information of an entity as an observable.

Now I want to requests all entity ids with the first function an then pipe those ids one by one into the second function to get one big observable with all my detailed entity informations.

Just to talk about the same functions:

```
this.api.getEntities()   -> gets all entity ids

this.api.getEntity(id)   -> gets information of a single entity
```

This is what i tried so far but its just working with when there is only one entity, with two or more entities id = 1, 2.

```
this.entities$ = this.api.getEntities().pipe(switchMap(id => this.api.getEntity(id)));
```

**My working solution now is:**

```
this.entities$ = this.api.getEntities().pipe(switchMap(ids => forkJoin(ids.map(id => this.api.getEntity(id)))));
```

Comment: Please share the return types of each of your method

Comment: return type is Observable<any>

Comment: Well, first define the correct types then! They should be `Observable<Array<number>>` and `Observable<Entity>` probably.

Comment: okay did that but still I don't know how to chain those two

Comment: Not really, the answer uses .map on an observable but I can't use .map I have to use .pipe(map( it => ........))

Comment: That's the old syntax, just put `map` and `flatMap` inside the `pipe`

Comment: okay thanks now it works, I will add my solution now. Maybe that helps someone else later too :)

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [RxJs Array of Observable to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984059/rxjs-array-of-observable-to-array)

```js
return this.api.getEntities()
  .pipe(
    flatMap((ids: Array<number>) => {
      return Observable.forkJoin(
        ids.map((id: number) => this.api.getEntity(id))
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe((entities: Array<Entity>) => {
    // Do something
  })
```

Comment: flatMap was renamed to mergeMap, but otherwise great answer!